# jQuery form validation error

Tags: jquery, validation

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="regform">
    <h4>Login info</h4>
    <hr><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
</form>
```

--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regform').on('submit', function(){
        alert($(this).username.val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

--

The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: $(...).username is undefined
```

Can't see what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
$(this).find('[name="username"]').val()
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5obqf53e/)

or alternatively `this.username.value` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
alert($(this).find('[name=username]').val());
```

or:

```
alert(this.username.value);
```

Accessing input elements as properties of the containing form is a DOM feature, not part of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you meant to do:

```
$(this).find("input[name=username]").val()
```

You can't just append `.username` to the end of a jquery object and hope for the right returned value.  You need to select the correct element from the dom.

Also, instead of "return false" you should do this:

```
$('#regform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```